# NLog custom layout renderer exception

Tags: c#, string, conditional-statements, nlog

I have the following custom layout renderer:

```
[LayoutRenderer("ignore-exception")]
public class ExceptionLoggingRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// What exception was thrown (used to check along with the Code)
    /// </summary>
    [RequiredParameter]
    public string Exception { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// What error code was thrown (used to check along with the Exception)
    /// </summary>
    [RequiredParameter]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        builder.Append(IgnoreLoggingToDb(Exception, Code));
    }

    private bool IgnoreLoggingToDb(string exception, string code)
    {
        if (exception == "whatever" && code == "123")
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Also, the following filters:

```xml
<filters>
    <whenEqual ignoreCase="true" layout="${ignore-exception:Code=82:Exception=${exception}}" 
action="Ignore" compareTo="true"/>

    <when condition="'${ignore-exception:Code=82:Exception=${exception}}'" 
action="Ignore"/>
  </filters>
```

Calling the logger:

```
Log.Error().Exception(e).Property("Code", (int)e.Code).Write()
```

These filters step into the custom layout renderer perfectly, however 
the property `Exception` in `ExceptionLoggingRenderer` becomes "${exception", i.e. the second curly bracket in ${exception} is treated as a closing one for my custom layout renderer.

I was not able to escape or find another way of getting the ${exception} layout renderer work inside my custom layout renderer via `<when condition="..." action="Ignore">`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to avoid using layout renderer for a custom layout renderer's parameter which takes `${exception}`.
I am just using a `LogEventInfo.Exception` from an overriden Append method:

```
protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
{
    var whatever = logEvent.Exception;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is the best, use `LogEventInfo.Exception`

But the nested `${exception}` will also work, if you're using the type `Layout` for the property Exception, and render it with the context of the logevent:

e.g:

```
[LayoutRenderer("ignore-exception")]
public class ExceptionLoggingRenderer : LayoutRenderer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// What exception was thrown (used to check along with the Code)
    /// </summary>
    [RequiredParameter]
    public Layout Exception { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// What error code was thrown (used to check along with the Exception)
    /// </summary>
    [RequiredParameter]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    protected override void Append(StringBuilder builder, LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        var exceptionString = Exception.Render(logEvent);
    }


}
```